# Uncaught TypeError on simple AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So If I run `$(".addButton").click(Task.requests.addTask);` to the method below:

```
addTask:function(aTask){
    console.log(aTask);
    if(typeof aTask === "undefined"){
        aTask = {name:"New Task",desc:"none"};
    }
    console.log(aTask);
    $.ajax({
        url:"/tasks/data/tasks",
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        data:aTask,
        success: function(){
            console.log("Added Successfully");
            Task.requests.allTasks();
            },
        error: function(err){
            console.error(err);
        }
    });

},
```

I get

```
undefined /*(from the first console.log(aTask))*/
{name: "New Task", desc: "none"} /*(from the second console.log(aTask))*/
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at i (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.param (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.addTask (tasks.js:67)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

In the console.
the  `at HTMLButtonElement.addTask (tasks.js:67)` Being the `$.ajax({` line and the AJAX request processes as expected with the object being sent properly and sending the correct data: `{name: "New Task", desc: "none"}` to the API(in Chrome, in Firefox it dies here).

If I remove the if conditional `if(typeof aTask === "undefined"){` which is in place to handle an empty parameter(which will be most of the time) and just set the `aTask` variable with no conditional, the `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` error goes away.

I feel like I'm missing something stupid here. Why am I getting the error with my typeof conditional added? The variable is being set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that was stupid. I forgot that the jquery click method returns the object clicked as it's first parameter. I'm not sure why Chrome was reporting it as undefined with the console.log.. I simply had to change my method to `addTask:function(obj,aTask){` and everything worked correctly.

Seems very odd the way Chrome handled it(throwing an error but still somehow sending the data?). Viewing it in the Firefox console seemed to correctly show that it was a button object.